# webdriver send_keys not working after context_click in Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

`send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)` is not working after right-clicking a link in Chrome. It works perfectly on Firefox.

If I do

```
context_click().send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

it should select the second option in the right click menu, however it just performs click.

In the following code, I want to open the link in a new tab, but it just opens in the same tab.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl")
driver.maximize_window()
elm_search_wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"gbqfq")))

elm_search_text = driver.find_element_by_id("gbqfq")
elm_search_text.send_keys("selenium")

bln_content_page = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.title_contains("selenium"))
blm_result_set = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//ol/div[@class='srg']")))

elm_result_set = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("g")
elm_result_1 = elm_result_set[0]
elm_search_link = elm_result_1.find_element_by_tag_name("a")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elm_search_link)
ActionChains(driver).context_click(elm_search_link).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an **alternative** that will work across both **Firefox and Chrome**:

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(elm_search_link).perform()
```

**This will simulate the "Control + Click" action on the link, that results in its opening in a new tab.**

Comment: Though it fulfills my need, but just wanted to understand why the above code does not work in chrome.

Comment: Truth is, I am also stumped as you are. Tried your code and modified in multiple possible ways that I could think of, but the result was nada. Even searching in google didn't give me any concrete results. Since, above alternative worked, I put it up here so that, at least you would've another way.. :)